# Free profinite completions

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which residually finite groups $G$ generated by $m$ elements, have the free profinite group on $n$ generators as their profinite completion?

Comment: I believe this is a more general version of a well known open question. See page 4 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5130.pdf

Comment: I'm aware of this paper. I do not think that this problem receives satisfactory treatment there.

Comment: Khalid is right, though, that this is a well known open question.  I recently heard Alan Reid give a talk about his joint work with Martin Bridson on this subject http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/areid/BCR_website.pdf.  Thm 1.2 gives examples of classes of groups whose profinite completions are not isomorphic to free profinite groups.